# HTML/CSS for mobile app. Footer with input behaves wrong when opening keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, mobile

I have a really tricky problem I have been trying to solve for weeks now.

I want to make a web chat for mobile devices. I have some speech bubbles and a footer that has an input box. The footer should always be on the bottom. And when the keyboard opens, it should move just above the keyboard that the user sees when what he writes.

That works so far. The tricky thing is to have the view with the speech bubbles scrollable so that I can scroll to the first message WITHOUT THE FOOTER MOVING ALONG.

[image: Before clicking text input field]
[image: After clicking text input field]

I had a version which only worked in Google Chrome (tested on iOS), but not in Safari:
http://marcback.es/work/sparkassenchat/v7

It is an ugly solution which involves Javascript Code etc.

Does any of you guys have a solution for that? The solution doesn't have to be pretty, it just needs to work. Please help :/

Comment: Make the chat window scrollable, and set fixed position to both header and footer input. U can do it by setting position:fixed property.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.I would need a JS function which determines the REAL visible height of the page (between top of page and keyboard)